# How can I move this code from static AngularJS/jQuery to dynamic AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to create in pure AngularJS a fill-in-the-blank activity which takes collection of records that contain phrases with markers where the blanks are, the correct answers, and incorrect answers to display along with them.

I've programmed a prototype in AngularJS/jQuery, below, which has the interactive functionality that I want, also here: http://jsfiddle.net/kkLdzngv/2/

What do I need to do to now is:

- replace all the jQuery code with AngularJS code
- make it dynamic so that not just one phrase is displayed, but all phrases in the collection are displayed with input fields each with the functionality that is in my prototype

In particular, I don't understand the correct AngularJS approach. I assume I need to use a `ng-repeat` to iterate through `$scope.texts` and inside the `ng-repeat` I would have my `<div class="item">`. But at that point, what functionality of AngularJS do I need to use to create the functionality shown in the prototype?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="text">Customer 1 is from <input id="record_1_blank_1" ng-change="checkEntry_record_1_blank_1()" ng-model="record_1_blank_1"/> and Customer 2 is from <input id="record_1_blank_2" ng-model="record_1_blank_2"/>.</div>
    <div class="answers">Munich, <span id="answer2">Berlin</span>, Frankfurt, Stuttgart, Hamburg</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.texts = [
    {
        body: 'Customer 1 is from [@@blank] and Customer 2 is from [@@blank].',
        correctAnswers: 'Berlin;Hamburg',
        incorrectAnswers: 'Stuttgart;Munich;Frankfurt'
    },
    {
        body: 'Company 3 is located in [@@blank].',
        answers: 'Bremen'
    }
];

$scope.checkEntry_record_1_blank_1 = function (obj) {
    if ($scope.record_1_blank_1 == 'Berlin') {
        $('#record_1_blank_1').css(
                {
                    background: 'lightgreen'
                })
                .attr('disabled', 'disable');
        $('#record_1_blank_2').focus();
        $('#answer2').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle/plnkr that simulates your problem?

Comment: yes you would use `ng-repeat` , other than that not sure what specific issues are here

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkLdzngv/2/ @charlietfl I know I could build this with jQuery as in the example, but I want to do it "the AngularJS way" and don't understand how to get all of the interactivity (as shown in the fiddle) done with AngularJS, e.g. how to replace the [@@blank] markers with `input` elements` and recreate the interactivity.